Expressing a multivariate normal distribution as a mixture of uniform distributions?
Context: Given a scalar normal distribution $X\sim \mathrm{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, it is possible to express $X$ as a mixture of uniform distributions over intervals (compound probability distributions), i.e., $X | V=v \sim \mathrm{Unif}(\mu-\sigma \sqrt{v},\mu+\sigma \sqrt{v})$ and latent variable $V\sim \Gamma(3/2,1/2)$, as shown in Qin et al. "Scale Mixture Models with Applications to Bayesian Inference".
Question: is it possible to generalize to the multivariate normal distribution as a mixture of uniform distributions over high dimensional balls parameterized by some latent variable?

Where does it say that in the linked paper?

2nd page first line.

$\newcommand\fm{f_{\max}}\newcommand\si\sigma\newcommand\Si\Sigma\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$Let $f$ be the p.d.f. of the normal distribution $N(\mu,\si^2I_n)$ over $\R^n$, where $\si>0$ is a real number and $I_n$ is the identity matrix. Then for all $x\in\R^n$
$$f(x)=\int_{(0,\infty)}dt\,1(t<f(x))=\int_{(0,\infty)}dt\,1(x\in B_t) \\
=\int_{(0,\fm)}dt\,|B_t|\frac{1(x\in B_t)}{|B_t|}
=\int_{(0,\fm)}dt\,p(t)f_t(x),$$
where $\fm:=\max f=(2\pi\si^2)^{-n/2}$,
$B_t:=\{x\in\R^n\colon f(x)>t\}$ -- which is a nonempty open ball in $\R^n$ centered at $\mu$ if $t\in(0,\fm)$, $|B_t|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $B_t$, $p(t):=|B_t|$, and $f_t$ is the p.d.f. of the uniform distribution over the ball $B_t$.
Thus, $N(\mu,\si^2I_n)$ is the mixture of the uniform distributions over the balls $B_t$, with the mixing p.d.f. $p$ supported on the interval $(0,\fm)$.
By a change of variables, we see that $N(\mu,\si^2I_n)$ is the mixture of the uniform distributions over the balls centered at $\mu$ with the mixing distribution of the radii being that of the random variable $\si\sqrt V$, where $V\sim\chi^2_{n+2}$, and the latter chi-squared distribution is the gamma distribution with parameters $\frac{n+2}2,\frac12$. In particular, for $n=1$ we get the result mentioned in the paper linked in your post.
(That $p$ is a p.d.f. follows because
$$1=\int_{\R^n}dx\,f(x)=\int_{(0,\fm)}dt\,p(t)\int_{\R^n}dx\,f_t(x)
=\int_{(0,\fm)}dt\,p(t).\ )$$
Remark: Similarly, any normal distribution $N(\mu,\Si)$ over $\R^n$ is a mixture of the uniform distributions over ellipsoids centered at $\mu$.
On the other hand, any mixture of the uniform distributions over balls in $\R^n$ centered at $\mu$ must be spherically invariant about $\mu$. So, a normal distribution $N(\mu,\Si)$ over $\R^n$ is a mixture of the uniform distributions over balls centered at $\mu$ if and only if $\Si$ is of the form $\si^2 I_n$, as was assumed above.

Thank you very much!
